# Why does it show value 5150 and not 155?

Tags: javascript

So im quite new to javascript and i tried making something simple as entering a value and add 150 to it but it wont show number + 150?
Pictures below

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjPJr.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcxER.png)

Comment: Dont mind the "check if your right" button, i was just messing around before i decided to make this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are concatenating strings.  You need to convert the strings to integers by using `parseInt()`, and then add the numbers.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

```
var fullprice = parseInt(price) + 150;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! But i do wonder why it doesnt work with just price + 150 cause none of them are string or am i wrong? :)

Comment: Yes, price is a string since you are using getElementById("pris").value to retrieve the value from HTML.

Comment: Even thought there is no need to use types in Javascript, there are! An input can contain a number but it's value is returned as a String. `typeof "5"` would return `string` and `typeof 5` would return `number`

Comment: Ah i see, so i would just use parseInt() to get number instead of string? :)

Comment: Yes. you can always check the type of a variable by using the `typeof` operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're actually concatenating a string with a number. The input value is a string, so before operating with it, parse it to int with parseInt

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thank you, i read through the link and it gave me a clearer picture :)